# Remove appended header from JSF page

Tags: java, jsf, facelets, portlet, jsf-1.2

I've written an `.xhtml` page with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>P</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm opening this page with JavaScript in a new window.

Unfortunately it's displayed as

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <div id="">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <p>P</p>
            </body>
        </html>
    </div>
</html>
```

This of course is invalid HTML. How can I remove those appended tags? And why are they created in the first place?

I'm using JSF 1.2, Facelets, the Portlet API 2.0 and JBoss PortletBridge.

Comment: You should use a template with <ui:insert > components and then in your page <ui:composition components.

Comment: Sounds much like as if the request URL fired by JS did not match `FacesServlet` URL pattern as specified in `web.xml`. Please verify this. I'm not sure what the role/influence of a portlet API is as I've never used it, so I am not posting this directly as an answer.

Comment: The pattern is `*.xhtml` and the URL ends with `.xhtml`.

Comment: Oh? Does that work for normal pages which you don't open by JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've now written a [`HttpServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html) for the pop-up to circumvent this problem. Since the file to which it's forwarding is ending with `*.jsp`, it's not affected by the [`FacesServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html) and no strange header gets appended.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the jsf head and body components:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:view>
        <h:head>
            <title>Test</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <p>P</p>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
    </html>
```

Comment: `h:head` and `h:body` are unfortunately only available in JSF 2.

Comment: You are not explaining why the problem occurs in first place.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a template with  components and then in your page

example
template

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
<h:head>
<title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>
<h:body dir="ltr">
<ui:insert name="content" />
</h:body>
</html>
```

and the a .xhtml page

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
<ui:composition template="${empty param.sl ? '/includes/template.xhtml' : '/includes/templatepopup.xhtml'}">
    <ui:define name="title">${msg.removeapplicant_title}</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">
        <f:view>


put your htlml here

</f:view>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</body></html>
</f:view>
```

Comment: Actually I've use a template and got the described problem. I've omitted it in the question just for simplicity.

Comment: You are implying that using template client is required in order to retrieve a proper HTML result. This is untrue.